# I have no icons or even launcher in ubuntu desktop

Tags: unity, error-handling

I'm new in ubuntu. I have installed ubuntu for one month, but during this time I encountered this problem (removing icons or even launcher from ubuntu desktop) for two times. this problem comes to me after running make command in terminal. in fact in the middle of make process I got error that was different in each times. when I closed terminal after getting error, I turned off computer then I turned it on but there was nothing on my desktop, neither icons nor launcher.

what is my problem? 
This problem forced me to reinstall ubuntu several times and this bothered me.
thank you for your attention.

Thank you Lorenzo
Now I reinstalled Ubuntu again. Unfortunately I didn't save those errors but I guess it will repeat again.
Infact, I wanted to install special software that I got the error. in it's installation guide had been said I must separate binary and source files from each other. I didn't know the difference between binary and source file therefore simply entered to software directory and ran ccmake comand then called make and got the error that I said before.
May be this explanation have a clue for solving my problem.
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have dependencies for the packages you are about to compile & install.

Now, try to reinstall your Graphic User Interface by writing this on a virtual terminal (press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login):

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome
(confirm)
```

...and after it has finished:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome
```

If it still can't work, issue from a virtual terminal (the same):

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The password asked is always your account password.

You will need a working internet connection. This is a really generic answer because your question has very few details. If you need more help comment under here and I will answer soon.

Good evening.

Edit: let's make some controls to solve your problem:

- Open a terminal (Gnome terminal or xterminal are OK) and execute `whoami`. It should output your current user and NOT `root` or any other user. If the user is different, login as Your user to the graphic interface.
- Execute `sudo apt-get check gnome` and verify the absence of errors. If there are errors correct them with `aptitude`.
- Be sure to be prompted for login at the system startup, otherwise install a login manager.
- If you still have troubles, logout and in the login panel select a different session type and then login. Continue until you find the right session type.
- Use `less /var/log/syslog` from a terminal to check for errors.
- Last hope, run `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log|grep WW` and report here any error.

Last note, in the mid time you solve, the "source files" are the text files used to compile a program (are the source code written by a programmer), and the binary files are the executables. Use the `file` command to see the file type or run `ls -lh` to have a colored output dependent on the file type. Never install untrusted software from exeternal repositories.

Comment: Hello. I have the same problem again but this time I couldn't get any error. I installed lapack and blas from synaptic successfully then I turned off my computer and now when I turn it on I have no icons and launcher on it. What is my problem? Please help me.

Comment: Thanks to Saurav Kumar for the corrections to my embarrassing English. A note to your edit to the question: the commands I posted didn't reinstall your Ubuntu OS, but only the user interface (called gnome). The third command `dist-upgrade` installed only some upgrades. I will edit my answer to make it more useful very soon. One moment. ;-)